# Test for field length in MySql statement

Tags: mysql, drupal

I am using this part of a sql statement to delete accounts with the specific phone number in a cronjob.php file.  How do I alter this statement to test for the length of a specific given field in the user-profies, rather than what I list here as the value being `LIKE '%2147483648%'`

```
$strSQL = "DELETE
            FROM users,
                 profile_values
           USING profile_values 
           INNER JOIN users USING(uid) 
           INNER JOIN profile_fields USING(fid)
           WHERE profile_values.uid=users.uid 
             AND profile_values.value LIKE '%2147483648%' 
             AND (profile_fields.name = 'profile_phone_number')";
execSQL($strSQL);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are testing for length of the data in the field, you can use code like:

```
... WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(profile_values.value)) = 10 ...
```

substituting the correct field name. The TRIM function is important to eliminate any leading or trailing spaces which might have crept in to the data.

Be careful using a function like this to automatically delete users. It will be quite indiscriminate.